# Issue with encrypting password using Crypt::RC4

Tags: perl

I am using Crypt::RC4 for encrypting password. But it is not able to encrypt the password containing '0' or '#'. In case of zero, program gets terminated whereas in case of # it is not able to encrypt.

I am new to Perl, I need this for my automation script. I am running the script on windows 64-bit.

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using, and the smallest bit of code you can write which displays this problem?

Comment: Can be closed under an official close reason: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers._

Answer (score 1):

***Script:***

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Crypt::RC4;

my $passphrase = 'abcde#01234';
my $plaintext = 'text with #0';

my $encrypted = RC4($passphrase, $plaintext);
print "Encrypted: ", $encrypted, "\n";
print "Encrypted: ", unpack('H*', $encrypted), " (hex)\n\n";

my $decrypted = RC4($passphrase, $encrypted);
print "Decrypted: $decrypted\n";
```

***Output:***

```
Encrypted: C0Þ%;1$Kíùt¬
Encrypted: 4330de253b31244bedf974ac (hex)

Decrypted: text with #0
```